# Why typeof null is 'object' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, null

Consider this code:

```
typeof null == 'object'//returns  true
```

And Consider this code:

```
typeof null == '' //returns  false
```

Why?

Comment: `typeof null == ''` returns false for me, as expected

Comment: @Tibos I was about to say that.

Comment: Same here. false for typeof null == ''.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv it is not related to my question

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ Well, `typeof null == ''` is a little obvious, right? `"object" == ""` returns `false`.

Comment: Actually, it is. The third answer states that "null is not an object, it is a primitive value. For example, you cannot add properties to it. Sometimes people wrongly assume that it is an object, because typeof null returns "object". But that is actually a bug (that might even be fixed in ECMAScript 6)."

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: it's been pretty much ruled out AFAIK, breaks too much.

Comment: Yup, that's what the answer says. That's why this is a duplicate.

Comment: Why are people upvoting duplicates (and answers to them)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> typeof(null) returns "object"

and

```
 typeof('') returns "string"!
```

Answer (score 9):

**[The history of “typeof null”](http://www.2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html)**

A long-standing bug, since the beginning of JS.